# printf doesn't display my string correctly - why?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

here's my code

```c
    int wordSize = 8; // defining a word size

    int *myArray = NULL;
    myArray = malloc(sizeof(char)*(wordSize+1)); // using malloc() so I always have a big enough array should wordSize change. Also to practice.

    int index = 0; // defining a variable to browse through myArray

    do
    {
        myArray[index] = '*';
        index++;
    }
    while(index < wordSize);

    myArray[wordSize] = '\0'; // filling myArray with '*' character and the null terminator /0

    printf("%s", myArray); // trying to display myArray, only a single '*' is printed

    printf("\n\n");

    int i=0;

    while(i < wordSize+1)
    {
        printf("%c", myArray[i]);
        i++;
    } // trying to display myArray with an other method, this time with success
```

Since

```
char string[] = "hello";

    printf("%s", string);
```

is working perfectly fine, I don't understand why `printf("%s", myArray);` isn't working and only displays a single `*`. The do/while loop shows 8 `*` as expected which means that my array is filled as it should.

EDIT : as asked in the comments, simplified my example as well as tried some solutions and some other possibilities.

Comment: `*displayedSecretWord[characterCount] = '\0';` is wrong because it attempts to access an element with index `characterCount` but `malloc(sizeof(int)*characterCount);` allocates only enough memory for indices from 0 to `characterCount`−1. Aside from that, edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `"This is because when my basic game will be working I want to be able to randomly choose from a list of words, so I can't have a fixed array."` -- You could have a maximum word size that is enforced, then you can also have a fixed-size array. However, if you prefer, you can of course also use `malloc`.

Comment: If you want an array of chars, then why did you make an array of ints?  Each time you increment the pointer, it moves 4 bytes (sizeof int), so you are skipping 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem.

```
int *myArray = NULL;
...
printf("%s", myArray);
```

You're trying to print an array of integers as if it was a string. I think that, by passing the wrong type of variable to `printf()`, you're going to invoke *undefined behavior*. It's also problematic that you only allocated enough memory for `wordSize+1` *bytes*, and then proceeded to write values into the array as if it was big enough for `wordSize+1` *integers*.

Fix this by changing the definition of `myArray`:

```
char *myArray = NULL;
```

The rest of the code, that accesses the members of this array, should now change from writing `int` values to writing `char` values. To be clear, I don't think you'll need to change anything. The compiler should do it for you, once `myArray` is properly defined as an array of `char`.

ETA:
More on what was happening in the original code.

Initially, you allocate 9 bytes. This is enough space for slightly more than 2 integers (assuming that `sizeof(int)` is 4). I'm also assuming that this memory was initially filled with zeroes.

The memory allocated to `myArray` looks something like this:

```
myArray[0] 00  00  00  00 
myArray[1] 00  00  00  00
myArray[2] 00
```

Then you go through and store 8 '*' characters in memory, which leaves memory looking like this:

```
myArray[0] '*' 00  00  00
myArray[1] '*' 00  00  00
myArray[2] '*'
```

Note that five more asterisks are written into memory that you do not own.
Then a "terminating zero" is written, again outside the memory that was allocated for `myArray`.

Then, you pass `myArray` — meaning, the address of the first byte in `myArray` — to `printf()`. You used the `%s` format specifier, so it's going to print a string. After it prints the first byte (an asterisk), the next byte it sees is a zero, so it stops.

Finally, you access individual integer members of `myArray` as if it was an array of eight integers (even though there isn't enough memory even for three). What this means is, the code reads the four bytes corresponding to `myArray[0]` into a temporary integer, and prints its value as if it was a character (because of the `%c` format specifier passed to `printf()`). As the loop continues, later regions of memory are read, including memory that doesn't belong to you. The observed results are that the asterisks are still where you wrote them.

Note that this is all based on assumptions about your development environment, your target architecture, and so on. The exact mechanism for what you observed is potentially interesting — but it is important to remember that it's all examples of **undefined behavior**. You should not rely upon it, because in a different system or on a different day the results could be radically different.

Comment: Thank for this explanation. Now, two things : 1) myArray is a pointer so why does it matter if it's an int or a char, if that's not exactly what we're modifying ? 2) why does the loop still works at displaying myArray even when it's an int when printf doesn't ?

Comment: Your ETA made it cristal clear, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If testCharacter is initialized with 0
I think you should use character pointer type for displayedSecretWord
and then allocate sizeof(char) * (characterCount+1) for displayedSecretWord.